# Finding which census tracts lie within a given shape?

Tags: r, sf

I'm new to GIS in R, and I am trying to create a crosswalk that maps the communities drawn in [these shapefiles](https://hub.arcgis.com/datasets/7b8a64cab4a44c0f86f12c909c5d7f1a_23) to census tract shapefiles for Los Angeles County that I've gathered from the Tigris package.

What I'd like is a list of census tracts that correspond to each geography--for instance, `Agoura Hills contains x,y,z tracts`, `Alhambra contains a,b,c tracts`, etc. The issue is that some of these places aren't cities but neighborhoods for larger cities which is why I can't just use total census to get what I need.

I'm not entirely sure, but I think what I might be trying to do is a spatial join?

Comment: You're probably looking for `st_intersects`. If you post some reproducible code, someone may be able to help you.